# Any alternative for cin.ignore?

Tags: c++

```
5 /*description: 
6 This program which approximates one root of a polynomial
7 in a closed interval of the real number line and use the 
8 bisection method to approximate the root.
9 */
10 
11 #include <iostream>
12 #include <string>
13 #include <sstream>
14 #include <vector>
15 #include <iomanip>
16 #include <cmath>
17      
18 using namespace std;
19 
20 double polynomial(vector<double>,double,double,int);  
21 
22 int main()
23 {
24     int iterations;
25     cout << "How many iterations? ";
26     cin >> iterations;//gets the number of iterations
27     
28     double left_point,right_point,middle;
29     cout << "Enter the endpoints of the interval containing the root: ";
30     cin >> left_point >> right_point;
31     cin.ignore();
32     
33     vector<double> coefficients;
34     cout << "Enter the polynomial coefficients, ascending in degree: ";
35     string line;
36     getline(cin,line);// gets an entire line of input
37     istringstream input_string(line); // use  input_string like cin
38        
39     double num;
40     while (input_string >>num)
41     {
42         coefficients.push_back(num);
43     }
44     
45     cout << "Root estimate: " << setprecision(8) //Print at least 8 significant digits
46          << polynomial(coefficients,left_point,right_point,iterations);
47     
48 }
49 
50 //function
51 double polynomial(vector<double> coefficients,double left_point,double right_point,int iterations)
52 {
53     double middle;
54     for (int n = 0; n < iterations; n++)
55     {
56         middle = (left_point + right_point) / 2; //use the bisection method
57         double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;
58         for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.size(); i++)
59         {
60             sum1 = sum1 + coefficients[i]*pow(left_point,i);
61             sum2 = sum2 + coefficients[i]*pow(middle,i);
62             sum3 = sum3 + coefficients[i]*pow(right_point,i);
63         }
64         
65         if (sum1*sum2 > 0)
66             left_point = middle;
67         else
68             right_point = middle;
69     
70     }
71     
72     return middle;  
73 }
```

Above is the program a friend of mine wrote for her project. But she's trying to find an alternative for `cin.ignore` because her professor prohibits the use of it. I can't think of any so I'm here to ask for help, and it can't be any other library function like clear.

Comment: Tell your friend to switch professors.

Comment: Please don't add line-numbers in the code you show, it makes it much harder for us to copy-paste and try ourselves.

Comment: Well, I should of specified that her professor wouldn't allow her to use library functions that she didn't learn before the project, which is why she couldn't use cin,ignore, but since she already knows it. it's hard for her to use something else, and I'm having the same problem as her as well. Dunno what to do.

Comment: As for a possible solution, think about what the `ignore` function might do internally.

Comment: Use `std::getline` exclusively, then you don't need `ignore`.

Comment: We are not in your friend's class and don't khow what exact material was taught to the students. Unless you specify a complete list of allowed/disallowed library facilities, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Well I don't think I can use getline for doubles right? And my friend said the professor wants her to do this without the use of library functions. Is there any way?